# Zeppelin: how to print pandas dataframe with index?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-zeppelin

For example

if I use `df.describe()` directly,

[image: ![enter image description here]

if I use `z.show(df)`, the result becomes

[image]

I can't know which is uniq, count etc from the `describe`.

How can I display pandas in full in Zeppelin?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [PR](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1358) it should display the index out of the box, but it doesn't work for me with Zeppelin **0.8**. As a workaround you can call [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```py
z.show(df.describe().reset_index())
```

The mentioned PR was merged into Zeppelin **0.9** and your can display the pandas dataframe properly with:

```py
z.show(df.describe(), show_index=True)
```